# Parsing URL using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I just tried to parse the given URL using GSON but I get some problems.

The url

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json

```
jsonFlickrFeed({
    "title": "Uploads from everyone",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/",
    .....)
```

The Json response is some thing like this . which contains a ({ in the begning of string which make problem in parsing.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

My model class is below like this:

```
 public class Flicker {

    public JsonFlickrFeed jsonFlickrFeed;

    public JsonFlickrFeed getDealList() {

        return jsonFlickrFeed;
    }

    public static class JsonFlickrFeed{

        public String title;
        public String link;
        public String description;
        public String modified;
        public String generator;
        public List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Flicker.Items>();

    } 

    public static class Items {

        public String title;
        public String link;
        public String media;
        public String date_taken;
        public String description;
        public String published;
        public String author;
        public String  author_id;
        public String  tags;
    }


}
```

Comment: Specify the problems, please

Comment: @josuadas specified can you please check again :)

Comment: yes! it´s clear now :)

Comment: Maybe first remove "(" and ")" from the beginning and from the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on Json and you can see that `media` is class:

```
"media": {"m":"http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3706/10153214694_177e2dcd6d_m.jpg"},
```

Therefore I added new class `Media` with `String m;`

BTW, you don't need to initiate `List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Flicker.Items>();`

Gson does that for you and convert any `List` to `LinkedList`

Here is a working code with fix:

**Launcher**

```
str = str.substring("jsonFlickrFeed(".length(), str.length()-1);

Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(str);
JsonFlickrFeed jj = gson.fromJson(str, JsonFlickrFeed.class);

System.out.println((jj != null)?"true":"false");
```

**Media**

```
public class Media {
    public String m;
}
```

**JsonFlickrFeed**

```
public class JsonFlickrFeed {
     public String title;
     public String link;
     public String description;
     public String modified;
     public String generator;
     public List<Items> items;
}
```

**Items**

```
public class Items {
    public String title;
    public String link;
    public Media media;
    public String date_taken;
    public String description;
    public String published;
    public String author;
    public String  author_id;
    public String  tags;
}
```